# How to use Curl in C++ to get http response string after sending http string to server

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

In a C ++ program I need to send an http message using Curl to another machine where is running a REST server written in C ++, and then collect the response from that server.

I am new to using Curl and have been looking at documentation and various examples on the web.

The source code of my program is the one attached below.

Sending the message to the server works, but I do not get the response the server sends me (not a timeout problem).

I would appreciate help with this, as I am not sure the code I use to get the response from the server is correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <curl/curl.h>



size_t getAnswerFunction(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string* data) {
    data->append((char*)ptr, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}



void sendDataAndGetAnswer(std::string data)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  struct curl_slist *httpHeaders=NULL;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if (curl)
  {
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.100:15000");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data.c_str());
    
    httpHeaders = curl_slist_append(httpHeaders, "MyProgram-Header");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, httpHeaders);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MyAgent/1.0");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000);

    // .........................................
    // MyProgram sends data.
    // This works right.
    // .........................................

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
      std::cout << "curl_easy_perform() failed to send message: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;


    // .........................................
    // MyProgram get answer.
    // This does not work.
    // .........................................

    std::string response_string;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.100:15000");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, getAnswerFunction);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response_string);
    // getAnswerFunction waits at most 5000 ms.
    // Afterwards, the flow of the program should continue even if there is no response.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 5000);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res == CURLE_OK)
      std::cout << response_string;
    else
      std::cout << "curl_easy_perform() failed to get answer: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;


    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_slist_free_all(httpHeaders);
  }
}



int main(void)
{

  while (1)
  {
    int valueVar = 0;
    // Execute various statements and perform calculations.
    // ...

    // Calculate value here.
    // ...

    std::string msgToSend("CONTITION-IS-TRUE");
    if (valueVar = 5)
      sendDataAndGetAnswer(msgToSend);
    
    sleep(10);
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say that "[t]his does not work", but ***how*** does it "not work"? What happens? What is supposed to happen? What is the expected output? What is the actual output? Please take some time to refresh [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and [edit] your question to elaborate.

Comment: Also, have you tried using a debugger to check what happens? For example by placing a breakpoint in `getAnswerFunction` to see what arguments it gets?

Comment: And when creating a [mcve], please try to make sure it doesn't contain any unrelated errors. Preferably create an exact minimal example that replicates the problem (only), and copy-paste it into the question as-is. I mention this because in the code you show you have `if (valueVar = 5)` which doesn't seem right.

Comment: When the program runs "res = curl_easy_perform(curl);" to get the answer from the server, the value of res is not CURLE_OK. Although the timeout is very large, I get timeout error.

Comment: My minimal reproductible example should compile and run if you add "valueVar = 5;! before "if (valueVar == 5)".

Comment: The source code that I attach here is the code of my original program, eliminating what I have considered superfluous and I have verified that it compiles correctly on Linux. I appreciate any help with using Curl in this program.

Comment: What is the *exact* output of your program? What does `curl_easy_strerror(res)` say? Please *[edit]* your question to show the output you get.

Comment: Consider enabling the [`CURLOPT_VERBOSE`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html) option to see what libcurl is doing internally, that may give you a clue where the problem is.